# RC integrator behavior

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrator

I am trying to implement an RC integrator circuit in my design. The purpose of this circuit is to convert input pulse signals swinging between 0 to 2.5V into a ramp signal. The integrator circuit was designed with a time constant of 2ms. The circuit is as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftHaZO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

According to the simulation results and the theoretical calculations for output voltage, for a 10Hz input pulsed signal, the output ramp signal should rise up to the level of 2.48V. Whereas in the PCB, I am finding the output voltage rising only till 2.06V.
I tried one more experiment with R1 = 20kohm and C1 = 100nF (time constant still at 2ms). With this combination, I am seeing the output ramp signal rising till 2.5V (approx.).
Both capacitors used were of ceramic type with a voltage rating of 16V.

Does this behavior have anything to do with the capacitor's charging current? What could be the reasons for this behavior?

Comment: Your circuit is not an integrator, it's an LPF. You have to feed your input as current in order for it to integrate.

Comment: Perhaps the probe is 1 M\$\Omega\$

Comment: @HKOB what will happen if the probe is 1Mohm?

Comment: Yes,it is a lowpass filter - however, it can be used (with some restrictions) as an integrator for frequencies far above the corner frequency (3 dB) . By the way - in principle, the same restrictioins apply also to opamp integrators, but mostly with a much lower 3dB frequency.

Comment: For "proper" integration and a time constant T=2ms the input frequency should be at least some hundreds of Hz. For a 10 Hz input, the time constant must be much larger.

Comment: Please note that I am not worried about the time constant. My doubt is regarding the max. voltage to which the capacitor is charging.

Comment: Independent on the parts values, the capacitor always is charged up to the input voltage (assuming an ideal capacitor without any leakage). In case the capacitor has leakage which acts like an internal parallel resistance, the final voltage is determinded by the resistive voltage divider rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your oscilloscope probe input loaded the circuit with 1 Mohm (normal for oscilloscopes, the peak voltage seen would be: -

2.5 volts \$\times\dfrac{1,000,000}{1,000,000 + 200,000} = \$ 2.08 volts

If you have a x10 facility on your probe (10 Mohm input resistance , the voltage would rise to about 2.45 volts.